# c# regular expressions find and extract number of giving length

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string such as:

"12/11/2015: Liefertermin   71994 : 30.11.2015 -> 27.11.2015"

And I want to extract the substring 71994, which will always be a number of 5 digits

I have tried the following with no success:

```
 private string FindDispo_InInfo()
    {
        Regex pattern = new Regex("^[0-9]{5,5}$");
        Match match = pattern.Match(textBox1.Text);

        string stDispo = match.Groups[0].Value;
        return stDispo;
    }
```

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` which are the anchors for start and end of string. `\d{5}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the anchors `^` and `$` with a word boundary `\b` and use a verbatim string literal:

```cs
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\b[0-9]{5}\b");
```

Or, you may use **numeric boundaries**, `(?<!\d)` on the left and `(?!\d)` on the right:

```cs
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)[0-9]{5}(?!\d)");
// Use RegexOptions.ECMAScript to only match ASCII digits with \d
// Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)[0-9]{5}(?!\d)", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

And you can access the value using `match.Value`:

```cs
string stDispo = match.Value;
```

Fixed code:

```cs
private static string FindDispo_InInfo(string text)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\b[0-9]{5}\b");
    Match match = pattern.Match(text);
    if (match.Success)
        return match.Value;
    else
        return string.Empty;
}
```

And here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/OEndbX):

```cs
Console.WriteLine(FindDispo_InInfo("12/11/2015: Liefertermin 71994 : 30.11.2015 -> 27.11.2015"));
// => 71994
```

However, creating a regex object inside the method might turn out inefficient. Better declare it as a static private read-only field, and then use inside the method as many times as necessary.

Comment: Note that `{5,5}` = `{5}`. Also, `^` matches the start of string and `$` matches the end of string, thus, your regex could not match the input. Also, just `\d{5}` will also match `12345` in `123456`, it might not be what you expect, that is why I suggest using word boundaries that require non-word characters to be on both sides of the 5-digit sequence.

Comment: your answer is most complete and fits better my needs

Comment: Another point: if the number can be glued to letters or underscores, `\b` will not return those matches. You will need `Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<![0-9])[0-9]{5}(?![0-9])");` then.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `(\d{5})` which will capture a number of length 5